# Active admin change default model admin_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm starting my first project with Active Admin.
To use another model for my users I use the following command :

```
rails generate active_admin:install User
```

After this I make this change in active_admin initializer :

```
config.authentication_method = :authenticate_user!
config.current_user_method = :current_user
```

I'm correctly login my application but on the home page I get this error :

```
undefined method `destroy_admin_user_session_path' for #<ActiveAdmin::Views::HeaderRenderer:0x007ff8fa086a60>
```

How can I fix it properly ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved by editing initializer :

```
config.logout_link_path = :destroy_user_session_path
```

Answer (score 2):

This is addition to @Awea answer. Use togather with that.

**Check rails routing table for `destroy_user_session`.**

For example devise token auth make route table entry like this:

```
destroy_user_session DELETE   /auth/sign_out(.:format) devise_token_auth/sessions#destroy
```

But default method for activeadmin logout link is `:get` and it will not work.

To make it worked properly add to *config/initializers/active_admin.rb* also and:

```
config.logout_link_method = :delete
```